# Responsive 2 Column Absolute Positioning

Tags: css, responsive-design, css-position

I have a one page layout with 2 sections (main-containers.) Each main-container has 100% height and width. I would like my image class "pic" in section two with absolute positioning to sit on the bottom of section two. As of right now it sits on the bottom of section one. I think I just don't have something cleared right. I am using (mobile first initializr) template. http://www.initializr.com

may not help much but here is the fiddle

DEMO http://jsfiddle.net/jfarr07/7dWeY/

HTML

```
 <div class="main-container3" id="sponsorship">
        <div class="main wrapper clearfix">
            <article>
                <header class="branding">
                 OH THE POSSIBILITIES
                </header> 
            </article>
        </div> <!-- #main -->
 </div> <!-- #main-container3 -->


<div class="main-container4" id="promotion">
<div class="wrap">
<div class="jared">
    <img class="pic" src="images/jared.png" /></div>
<div class="jaredinfo"></div>

</div>
</div> <!-- #main-container4 -->
```

CSS

```
body {
height:100%;
overflow:scroll;
}
html {
height:100%;
}
article, aside, header {
display:block; 
}
}
.main-container3 {
background-image:url(../images/gopherbackground.png);
background-position:center center;
background-repeat:no-repeat;
background-size:cover;
-webkit-background-size: cover;
-moz-background-size: cover;
-o-background-size: cover;
min-height:100%;

}
.main-container4 {
background-image:url(../images/graybackground.png);
background-position:center center;
background-repeat:no-repeat;
background-size:cover;
-webkit-background-size: cover;
-moz-background-size: cover;
-o-background-size: cover;
min-height:100%;
}
.wrap {
width:90%;
margin:0 auto;
height:100%;
min-height:100%;
}
.jared {
background-color:#0C6;
float:left;
position:relative;
height:100%;
min-height:100%;
width:40%;
}
.jaredinfo {
background-color:#C60;
float:right;
position:relative;
height:100%;
min-height:100%;
width:60%;
}
.pic {
position:absolute;
bottom:0;
}
.branding {
font-size:44px;
color:#FFF;
font-family: source-sans-pro, sans-serif;font-weight:700;
text-align:center;
}
.wrapper {
width: 90%;
margin: 0 5%;
max-width:1000px;
}
.main {
padding: 30px 0;
}
```

Comment: You really should provide a better fiddle. Currently nothing can be seen because of colors and missing backgrounds.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I guess the problem might be that die 2nd container effectively has a `height` of zero. One solution could be to set a fixed `height`:

```
.main-container4 {
    height: 100px;
}
```

[Here is a demo](http://jsfiddle.net/7dWeY/12/).

If you want it to have 100% height, you need to set

```
html { height: 100%; }
```

too (along with `height: 100%` on the container). [Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/7dWeY/13/).

Comment: Linus this is exactly what I want but with a height of 100%.

Comment: ...so the image will sit on the bottom of the section. "jared" and "jaredinfo" would be 100% height to match main-container4 height.

Comment: Well I confirmed it all works in the fiddle. Some reason it's still sitting up in section 1. So it's definitely a clearfix  problem. I'm not clearing something somewhere.

Comment: Real question comes when you try to get 100% height after clearfix.